# portrait mode on one view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I think I have been through probably 50 versions of this question today.  The closest answer I got was putting

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: (UIWindow *)window{
```

into my app delegate and

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

into the view controller I want to restrict to portrait mode.  In this setup what I found is that the methods in my view controller never get called.  The method in my appdelegate gets called whenever I do a tab bar based segue, but not when I do a push segue in a navigation controller.

I've seen several answers that want me to subclass navigation controllers, but there has to be a more straight forward way.

I have an app with three tabs.  Tab 1 is just a home screen.  Tab 2 has a navigation controller feeding through two tableviewscontrollers, and the last table view segue's into a simple view controller.  Tab three goes to one tableviewcontroller which then does a push segue into the same simple view controller where tab 2 terminates.

I want that terminating view controller to always be in portrait.  The other scenes should be able to switch between portrait and landscape as needed.

I am in xcode5 IOS7.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to the question is that good apps fall into one of three categories: portrait-only apps, landscape-only apps, and apps that support both orientations in all view controllers.

The UX design goal: the user controls the app, the app **does not** control the user.

An app that has some view controllers that are portrait-only, and some view controllers that support rotation, is an app that is trying to control the user.  Specifically, when the user navigates to the portrait-only view, the app is forcing the user to physically rotate the device in response to the app's whims.

In short, given that you have a view controller that only supports portrait, you should design a portrait-only app.  If you don't want a portrait-only app, then you need to figure out how to support rotation on that last view controller.

Comment: you are right, it is taking the easy out and is not the best way to handle it.  But you have to admit the argument about the user controlling the app instead of the app controlling the user, is really ironic considering it's an apple device we are talking about.  LOL